# Bi-directional progressive loading in tabulator

Tags: infinite-scroll, tabulator, bidirectional

I'm looking to load a large quantity of data within tabulator and running into performance issues. Having only the small subset of records that are visible loaded would be ideal.

Reading through the documentation I could use progressive loading with an ajaxurl to load data as the user scrolls down the table with **ajaxProgressiveLoad** set to **scroll**.

Is there any way to discard the data that the user has scrolled past to keep the memory footprint low. This would also require the ability to reload it if they scroll upwards. Essentially a bidirectional infinite scroll.

I presume this could be implemented by modifying the existing ajax module, would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.